# Python how to print text with linebreak when it contains '\n'

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, line-breaks

I have text like `n"sdfsdfdsf \n sdfdsfsdf \n sdfdsfdsf..."`n. I need to print this text but every time there is a `\n`, I need to print a linebreak and print the body of text as broken up into separate lines.

how can I do this?

Edit1:
I am getting this text from a socket transaction and I just want to print it in a pretty manner.

`b'\r\n\r\nSERIAL Debugger\r\n--------------\r\n>fyi * -\r\nThis is a test: 0 (-)\r\nthis is a test\r\nnew level(-)\r\`

Comment: Please make a minimum reproducible example

Comment: normally print("sdfsdfdsf \n sdfdsfsdf \n sdfdsfdsf...") gives you new lines

Comment: How are you exactly trying to use print ? It works perfectly on python2 & python3 !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have binary data, and Python doesn't know how you want to print it. So decode it, knowing the encoding the data is in (I used UTF-8):

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 23 2017, 16:49:06)

>>> text = b'\r\n\r\nSERIAL Debugger\r\n--------------\r\n>fyi * -\r\nThis is a test: 0 (-)\r\nthis is a test\r\nnew level(-)\r\n'

>>> print(text)
b'\r\n\r\nSERIAL Debugger\r\n--------------\r\n>fyi * -\r\nThis is a test: 0 (-)\r\nthis is a test\r\nnew level(-)\r\n'

>>> print(text.decode())


SERIAL Debugger
--------------
>fyi * -
This is a test: 0 (-)
this is a test
new level(-)
```

But converting the data for the sake of printing sounds wrong.

Comment: It's *not* wrong, this is exactly how you're supposed to do things especially in Python 3. When you've got a pile of bytes you need to apply an intelligent conversion to characters.

Comment: @MarkRansom I said it sounds wrong for the sake of printing. Because an application usually doesn't print. Printing is done usually for debugging.